# database reflection throws error in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use reflect feature of sqlalchemy but running into issues.

This is the **mysql table i am trying to reflect**.

```
| Country | CREATE TABLE `Country` (
  `Code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `IsValid` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**Reflecting code(sch.py).**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy
import eng

#Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
Base = declarative_base()

country = Table('Country',eng.Meta,autoload=True)
class Country(Base):    
    __tablename__ = country
    __mapper_args = {
        'primary_key' : [country.c.Code]
    }
```

**eng.py**

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.orm

eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://user:pass@host/db',echo=True)

Meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
Meta.bind = eng

sesDec = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=eng)
```

When i `import sch` i get error.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sch import Country
import eng

ses = eng.sesDec()

res = ses.query(Country.Code.label('Code'),Country.Country.label('Country'))

for rec in res.filter(Country.IsValid == 'Y').filter(Country.Code.like('A%')).order_by(Country.Code).all():
    print rec
```

**Error(bottom of stack-trace)**

```
  File "/pythonlib/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 4198, in description
    return self.name.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'encode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Country(Base):    
    __tablename__ = country
```

Did you mean `__table__ = country`?

Comment: yes. thx. seems like i overlooked it! doc should highlight such subtle differences!

Comment: @tuxuday, sorry that I don't have experience of using foreign-keys in sqlalchemy, but if you can do something to make your goal, why don't you do that?